# 14.04: How to convert mysql to postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

is there anyway to convert a mysql file (.sql) to a postgresql file?

I have a number of tables and creating them all over again in phppgadmin is gonna take a lot of time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ? -- https://github.com/lanyrd/mysql-postgresql-converter ; Read through it, it's pretty self-explicit

Comment: I would require Python right?

Comment: Yes. sudo apt-get install python and sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pgloader](http://pgloader.io/). It can connect directly to your MySQL database and copy everything to PostgreSQL, converting all the tables.

You can get it from the official [PostgreSQL Apt Repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/), that will take care of dependencies. No need to compile.